# Some values in optimal solution are still violating the constraint limits in Matlab FMINCON

Tags: mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I am using fmincon function of Matlab for motion optimization of 6dof robotic arm. The  constraints that I consider, are the set of nonlinear constraint/equations. The objective and set of constrains are written below.

objective = @(h) h(1)+h(2)+h(3)+h(4)+h(5)+h(6)+h(7)+h(8)+h(9); subjected to following constraints 1 Ve(i)=[(w(i+1)/2)*h(i)+(q(i+1)-q(i))/h(i)+((w(i)-w(i+1))*h(i))/6] =<400
2 Jerk(i)= [(w(i+1)-w(i))/h(i)]=<240
3 A(i)= [(w(i)/(h(i)))*(t(i+1)-tx) + (w(i+1)/(h(i))) * (tx-t(i))] =<250

I have obtained results of objective functions which are;
hi (1.7372,11.5479,1.9821,0.8572,0.2308,3.1043,2.3440,2.2312,2.0215)

However after plotting, I have seen that some points are still violating the limits. For example no constraints are satisfied at the value of (11.5479).  In addition following message also appears

Solver stopped prematurely.
fmincon stopped because it exceeded the function evaluation limit,
options.MaxFunctionEvaluations = 3000 (the default value).

May I know the reason to not getting the optimal value on some points such as in case of (11.54)  .Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: What happens if you increase the function evaluation limit?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have seen no change in the results even by increasing the evaluation limit. For example following results were obtained at the evaluation limit of 5000/7000/8000/11000.                                                                                     
 1.7372   11.5479    1.9821    0.8572    0.2308    3.1043    2.3440    2.2312    2.0215